# Concatenate min/max filename through multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple filenames in multiple folders, which I walk though and append to a list:

```
/folder1/F004C007_190925_MN99.0120001.arx
/folder1/F004C007_190925_MN99.0120002.arx
...etc
```

Then I have a list which may or *may not* contain the first part of the filename, eg:

```
F004C007_190925_MN99
F004C008_190925_MN99
```

I have the following 2 functions to go and find matching patterns in the 2 lists:

```
def cleanfiles(f):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\D\d\d\d\D\d\d\d_\d\d\d\d\d\d_....')
    for z in f:
        m = re.search(pattern, z)
        if m:
            cleanedfiles.append(m.group())

def compare_intersect(x, y):
    fs = frozenset(x).intersection(y)
    for x in fs:
        matchedm.append(x)
        print(G+ "Match: " + P + x)
```

What I'd like to do afterwards, is in the new, matched 'cleanedfiles' list go and append the min and max numbers that appear between the 2 periods.

So the list would go from:

```
F004C007_190925_MN99
F004C008_190925_MN99
```

To:

```
F004C007_190925_MN99.[00120001-0120843].arx
F004C008_190925_MN99.[00100001-0100227].arx
```

But I have no idea on how I should approach this!

Comment: why can't you grab to whole filename right in the beginning and put it to your list?

Comment: I can, and do - but it's just a list of files. I want the list to be:
(unique_name).(min)-(max).extension

Comment: so what you need is a dictionary with the `unique_name` name as keys and the extensions as values maybe